# how to develop UI for desktop application using TELERIK

Tags: c#, user-interface, telerik, desktop-application

i want my interface to look more elegant though professional and i want to make it good as web/android UI's. But how do i do it? I have heard about TELERIK UI. but i have no idea about how to use it. I have downloaded it and initialised it but do not know what and how to do next. any help would be really appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: There is so much documentation and forums provided by Telerik that you should start looking at their homepage at www.telerik.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start here 
http://www.telerik.com/winforms/winforms-guide
http://www.telerik.com/videos/wpf

If you are not super attached to Telerik you can also look at Electron for native desktop apps (as it should have slightly easier learning curve):
http://electron.atom.io/